# add expected-color column to heatmap-like plot (seaborn)

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I have an expanded probleme from this post [Write values in heatmap-like plot, but for categorical variables in seaborn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64373550/write-values-in-heatmap-like-plot-but-for-categorical-variables-in-seaborn)

I would like to have an extra column on the left size of my plot for the expected color of this row, for example:

[image]

the expected color for each row is not only one color but can 2, 3 or more, so I would be happy if some one give me suggestion/solution

this is color-dataframe:

```
color = pd.DataFrame({'1.row':['#002b80','',''],
                     '2.row':['#0044cc','#002b80',''],
                     '3.row':['#4d88ff','#002b80',''],
                     '4.row':['#99bbff','',''],
                     '5.row':['#ccddff','#99bbff',''],
                     '6.row':['#ff6600','',''],
                     '7.row':['#ff944d','',''],
                     '8.row':['#ffc299','#ff944d','#ff6600'],
                     '9.row':['#2d862d','',''],
                     '10.row':['#66cc66','#2d862d','']})
```

Comment: i would build up the figure and `Axes` objects directly using matplotlib and use `ax.imshow` for your left-most plots

Comment: do you mean a subplot on the left?

Comment: yeah, that's what you're asking about, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create two subplots and put a `pcolormesh` inside each.

For the expected values, you can create a 10x6 matrix. (Where 6 is the LCM of 1, 2 and 3).
Things seem easier when just working with numbers instead of strings. The rows with one value will be put into 6 cells, the rows with 2 values will be put into 3 cells each, and similarly for 3 values.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

color = pd.DataFrame({'1.row': ['#002b80', '', ''],
                      '2.row': ['#0044cc', '#002b80', ''],
                      '3.row': ['#4d88ff', '#002b80', ''],
                      '4.row': ['#99bbff', '', ''],
                      '5.row': ['#ccddff', '#99bbff', ''],
                      '6.row': ['#ff6600', '', ''],
                      '7.row': ['#ff944d', '', ''],
                      '8.row': ['#ffc299', '#ff944d', '#ff6600'],
                      '9.row': ['#2d862d', '', ''],
                      '10.row': ['#66cc66', '#2d862d', '']})
color_list = ['#bae4b3', '#66cc66', '#2d862d', '#ffc299', '#ff944d', '#ff6600',
              '#ccddff', '#99bbff', '#4d88ff', '#0044cc', '#002b80']
cmap = ListedColormap(color_list)
norm = plt.Normalize(vmin=0, vmax=len(color_list) - 1)
expected_values = np.zeros((len(color.columns), 6))
for i, col in enumerate(color):
    c1, c2, c3 = color[col]
    if not c2:  # only one color: c1
        expected_values[i, :] = color_list.index(c1)
    elif not c3:  # two colors: c1 and c2
        expected_values[i, :3] = color_list.index(c1)
        expected_values[i, 3:] = color_list.index(c2)
    else:  # three colors: c1, c2 and c3
        expected_values[i, :2] = color_list.index(c1)
        expected_values[i, 2:4] = color_list.index(c2)
        expected_values[i, 4:] = color_list.index(c3)

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols=2, gridspec_kw={'width_ratios': [1, 7]})
ax1.pcolormesh(expected_values, cmap=cmap, norm=norm)
ax1.invert_yaxis()
ax1.axis('off')
mesh = ax2.pcolormesh(np.arange(0.5, 11), np.arange(0.5, 11), np.random.randint(0, 11, (10, 10)),
                      cmap=cmap, norm=norm, ec='white')
ax2.set_xticks(range(1, 11))
ax2.set_yticks(range(1, 11))
ax2.invert_yaxis()
for spine in ax2.spines.values():
    spine.set_visible(False)
cbar = fig.colorbar(mesh, ax=ax2)
cbar.set_ticks(np.linspace(0, 10, 23)[1::2])
cbar.ax.yaxis.set_ticklabels(range(0, 11))
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

Comment: hey thank you so much, it works. When My expected Color have between 2 to 8 different Colors, that means I Need 10*840 Matrix?

Comment: Yes. If that wouldn't work well, something like a 10x64 matrix and using one less or one extra position when the number isn't a true divider, will be quite indistinguishable. Other approaches are possible, but matplotlib usually doesn't have a problem with a 10x840 matrix.

Comment: I tried witgh 10*840 Matrix and it works. Is it possible to add a White line between each row but not between columns? because when I use

 edgecolor='white'

then all the plot on the left will turn be white

Comment: You could try something like `for i in range(1, 11): ax1.axhline(i, color='white', lw=2)`